# Action url to pass parameters to route

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I've a form in my view with two selects that I use to filter PRODUCTS by category or (not and) by shop.

I try to make the route url in this way:

/products/{filter}/{key}

Where filter is **category** or **shop** and key the slug of related item.
Some example:

/products/category/tablet

/products/category/mac

or

/produtcs/shop/eprice

/products/shop/amazon

Then in my route I think something like:

```
Route::get('/products/{filter}/{key}', 'PageController@products');
```

**The question**

How can I generate the action url in the form to make this route
working?

Comment: With your route, it's difficult to identify the filter as by category or by shop so you need one extra parameter to identify this. Another way is to use two different route like this: **Route::get('/products/shop/{key}', 'PageController@productsByShop');** and **Route::get('/products/category/{key}', 'PageController@productsByCategory');**

Comment: I've no problem to make two routes but the question remain, my action url in the form need to change in /products/category/{key} or  /products/shop/{key}. How?

Comment: Use javascript to change url based on category or shop selected

Comment: You dont have to use JS for this...

Comment: natas, it isn't the obvious causing the error? `fitler` should be `filter` surely? Oh just noticed you have done `produtcs` too surely this is `products` no?

Comment: this is only typo here in stockoverflow not in my code. How to achieve this without js?

Answer (score 0):

After changing routes remember to clear cache:

```
php artisan route:cache
```